# Delete particular string while reading CSV data

Tags: python, csv

I'm new in python , and I'm writing a code to read data from a CSV file.

The data looks like this:

```
10944750,13451,0,6��4��   

10944750,21110,0,6��7��

10944750,1131,0,7��23��

10944750,8689,0,5��2��
```

The last column represents date , for example in first row : June 4th . But there are two Chinese charter in it . So I have to decode it and get the month and day.

My code :

```
import codecs
raw_file=open('Documents/t_alibaba_data.csv')
result=open('Documents/result.txt','w')
for line in raw_file.readlines():
    entry=line.split(",")
    deco=entry[3].decode("gbk")
    month=deco[0]
    if len(deco)==5:
        day=int(deco[2])*10+int(deco[3])
    else:
        day=int(deco[2])
    result.write(",".join(entry[:3])+","+str(month)+","+str(day)+"\n")
        print result
```

There is no alert or error in my IDE, but there is nothing in my result either.

Comment: Why do you print `result` since it's a file object? What if you print `month` or `day`? And, there won't be Nov or Dec in your case, right?

Comment: I  delete last sentence and nothing in result.txt . There won't be Nov or Dec , month<10. @neuront

Comment: Have you deleted `result.flush()` or `result.close()`?

Comment: No `result.close()` or `result.flush()` in loop. I `result.close()` when the loop finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: you haven't told Python that you want to read from the file. (add 'r' to raw_file.open().

And, when running your program, after decoding the last column, element nr 3 (deco[2]) is a chinese symbol, not the nr of day.

I adjusted your program a little, and when it looks like this, it works (at least if I understood your question correctly):

```
import codecs
raw_file=open('Documents/t_alibaba_data.csv', 'r')
result=open('Documents/result.txt','w')
for line in raw_file.readlines():
    entry=line.split(",")
    deco=entry[3].decode("gbk").strip()
    month=deco[0]
    if len(deco)==5:
        day=int(deco[2])*10+int(deco[3])
    else:
        day=int(deco[4])
    result.write(",".join(entry[:3])+","+str(month)+","+str(day)+"\n")
result.close()
```

Also, len(deco) is never 5, and the if test will never be true. The length is *always* longer than 5. Try printing out the length of the different decos to see what the actual length is.
It could be wise to use the strip function on deco, in case there are spaces at the end of the string. When I print the length of the decos you gave as examples, the length was 8 or 9, depending on the line that were being processed.

Comment: Thank you , I found that when I `deco=entry[3].decode("gbk")` and `print deco` in mac os and windows , the result on screen is different . In windows looks like `6月4日` , and in mac is looks like this  `/u11111/u111/n` .